# Can Karabiner (aka KeyRemap4Macbook) remap arbitrary simple keys?

Tags: keyboard

Karabiner has a comprehensive set of *predefined* key remappings. But what about a simple

> remap '`' to '$'

(and vice versa)

Yes this can be done via Mac Input Sources. But they are cumbersome (and poorly documented). It would be nice to simply do those in Karabiner already.